# return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.OperationalError: table customer_ordermod el has no column named created_on

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I want to build a food delivering app, but facing this error.

> return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: table customer_ordermodel has no column named created_on

this is the view.py

```
from ast import Return
from multiprocessing import context
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .models import MenuItem, Category, OrderModel


class Index(View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'customer/index.html')


class About(View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'customer/about.html')


class Order(View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # get every item from each category
    appetizers = MenuItem.objects.filter(
        category__name__contains='Appetizer')
    main_course = MenuItem.objects.filter(
        category__name__contains='Main Course')
    desserts = MenuItem.objects.filter(category__name__contains='Dessert')
    drinks = MenuItem.objects.filter(category__name__contains='Drink')

    # pass into context
    context = {
        'appetizers': appetizers,
        'main_course': main_course,
        'desserts': desserts,
        'drinks': drinks,
    }
    # render the templates
    return render(request, 'custormer/order.html', context)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    order_items = {
        'items': []
    }

    items = request.POST.getlist('items[]')

    for item in items:
        menu_item = MenuItem.objects.get(pk=int(item))
        item_data = {
            'id': menu_item.pk,
            'name': menu_item.name,
            'price': menu_item.price
        }

        order_items['items'].append(item_data)

        price = 0
        item_ids = []

        for item in order_items['items']:
            price += item['price']
            item_ids.append(item['id'])

        order = OrderModel.objects.create(price=price)
        order.items.add(*item_ids)

        context = {
            'items': order_items['items'],
            'price': price

        }

        return render(request, 'customer/order_conformation.html', context)
```

this is my model.py

```
from time import strftime
from unicodedata import category, name
from django.db import models


class MenuItem(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='menu_image/')
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
category = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='item')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class OrderModel(models.Model):
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
items = models.ManyToManyField(
    'MenuItem', related_name='order', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'Order: {self.created_on.strftime("%b %d %I: %M %p")}'
```

here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
  return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

  The above exception (table customer_ordermodel has no column named 
  created_on) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
  **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
  return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 119, in dispatch
  return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  
  File"C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop
   \li'lbites\littlebites\customer\views .py", line 62, in post
  order = OrderModel.objects.create(price=price)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
  return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 514, in create
  obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 806, in save
  self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 857, in save_base
  updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1000, in _save_table
  results = self._do_insert(
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1041, in _do_insert
  return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
  return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1434, in _insert
  return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1621, in 
  execute_sql
  cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
  return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
   packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
  return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in 
  _execute_with_wrappers
  return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
  with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
  raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
   packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya\OneDrive\Desktop\li'lbites\.venv\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
  return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

  Exception Type: OperationalError at /order/
  Exception Value: table customer_ordermodel has no column named 
  created_on
```

so this my problem I have tried many solutions still not getting the problem here. As I can see that there is no problem in my core code but there is some internal issues, but still I can't run my program without solving them.

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` ?

Comment: yes I did. but still the same